# Why is my image not showing in my div?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I am showing on a page.  Here is my `css`:

```
body {
    background: url(./../imgs/beach.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

When I do this, everything shows just fine.  I then try to show the same image in a `div`.  Here is my `html`:

```
<body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
```

And here is my new `css`:

```
.background-image {
    background: url(./../imgs/beach.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

But now nothing shows.  I look in my network tab and I see that the `image` is available, but it is not showing on the page.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the div is 0 pixels tall, give it some height, for example:

```
.background-image {
    background: url(./../imgs/beach.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Why did I not have to give it a height when it was attached to the body?

Comment: here is a good reference: https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only using background you need to set a height/width on the div itself.

```
.background-image {
    background: url(./../imgs/beach.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: */Your Value/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest remove background-size: 100%; .. instead add height and width as 100%.

```
 body {
        background: url(./../imgs/beach.png) no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: I can't use `%` for width.  I have to set a specific width or nothing shows.

Comment: @jhamm that's a bummer.. try if this works..

`
body{
 height: 100%;
        width: 100%; 
}
.background-image {
    background: url("Desert.jpg") no-repeat;
        height: inherit;
        width: inherit;
}`